# Would a Core 2 Quad Q6600 Be a good replacement for a Core 2 Duo E7500

Tags: cpu, gaming, screen-recorder

I really need an upgarde for my PC, currently it has a [Core 2 Duo E7500](http://ark.intel.com/products/36503/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E7500-3M-Cache-2_93-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB?q=Core%202%20Duo%20E7500), and I was wondering if a [Core 2 Quad Q6600](http://ark.intel.com/products/29765/Intel-Core2-Quad-Processor-Q6600-8M-Cache-2_40-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB?q=q6600) would improve my peformance.

I am currenlty having problems recording gameplay. For example minecratf, ingame I get about 100FPS but the recording is only 20FPS and freezes every 5 seconds.

I definetly know the bottle neck is not my GPU since when I look at GPU-Z while recording and playing it is only at about 70% load, and I can even decrase that by limiting the fps ingame to 50%. one bottle neck could be the ram since im only running 2GB, (i know its not enough in 2016) while recoring  it os at about 85%. But the CPU is the worst, as while recoring and playing it is constatly at about 99% usage.

Cheapo-PC Specs:

---

CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo  E7500 @ 2.93Ghz 
GPU: GT 610 1GB
RAM: 2GB DDR2 667Mhz 
MOTHERBOARD: MSI G31TM-P35 
HDD: WD Caviar Blue 250GB & 320GB 
PSU: 350W 
Case: Shelf
OS: Windows 10 Home 64x
AV: AVG Free 2016, MalwareBytes, HitmanPro

(I used 3 old PC's to create this so be quiet)

Comment: Sounds like your bottleneck is less in the CPU and more in HDD write speed or RAM capacity.

Comment: what analysis of the issue have you performed? are both CPUs working steadily whilst playing/recording? What is your video card? you need a video card that supports OpenGL hardware acceleration to offload the work to the GPU, and many game recording systems integrate with the vidcard. only in the case that the CPU is short on thread execution capacity would it make sense to downgrade the 7500 to a chip two years older just to get two additional cores.

Comment: First step: Identify the bottleneck. If you already have done this then please add it to the post eding the [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1112455/edit) link. Likely bottlenecks are not just the CPU, but also the graphics card, and upgrading the wrong one (and not the other) wil not yield significant benefits.

Comment: Also note that the Quad chip might actually perform worse if the app is single treaded. (See the comparision [here](http://ark.intel.com/compare/36503,29765), but basically the quad runs at a lower speed and uses more power).

Comment: An up to date graphics card such as anything above a GTX660 or GTX700 series would include hardware video output capture and would effectively make this a non-issue.

Comment: Frank Thomas, both CPUs run good, and my current GPU is a GT 610 1GB,  I am a light gamer so this works well for me as I get about 100-300fps ingame while playing minecraft

Answer (score 1):

No it would not.

The E7500 has better single core performance and  switching to Q6600 will not make a big difference.

Coupled with the fact that most games do not take advantage of multiple cores up until recently, you are better off buying a faster hard drive or even an SSD, or alternatively I would recommend to to record your videos on an secondary storage device (or an external one). This way your hard drive will not have to do 2 things at the same time: that is reading the game files and writing the recorded footage. This will give you the biggest performance increase.

Comment: Ok, yes, I do have a secondary 320GB WD Caviar Blue, ill try recording to that.

Comment: Also try closing all unnecessary programs when recording, that will help too,